# Draw connector between MDI children in Windows Form

Tags: winforms, mdi

In Windows Forms, I would like to show relationships using lines to show a connection between two forms inside an MDI parent similar to MS Access' relationship diagram.

[image: ms access relations]

What are my options for drawing lines underneath the children (or on parent background)?

Comment: I don't know if that would be a mdi child or a tool window or perhaps moveable components that looks like a tool window.

Comment: The screenshot of Access shows MDI children for sure as they cannot be moved outside the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use MDI then what you would need to do is handle the `Paint` event of the `MdiClient` control that hosts the child forms.  It's not actually exposed directly but you can access is via the `Controls` collection of the parent form.  It will be the only child control of that type and, in most cases, the only child control.  You can then use GDI+ to draw lines between the appropriate pairs of forms.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney! I ended up using `MdiClient.OnMdiClientPaint()` and `e.Graphics.DrawLine()`